# Insights into Word/Document Embeddings

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec

How to get insights into my created word or document embeddings?

For example if I extract features with the `TF-IDF Vectorizer`, I can output the top n best features. Is there a similar approach where I can gain knowledge about the model?

Comment: What sorts of insights do you mean? What have you tried, and did it make sense, or disappoint compared to what you expected? Many of these techniques are best used for specific tasks. Thus if you develop a repeatable quantitative evaluation – does the end result deliver good similarity/recommendation results? does the end result classify things properly? – that usefulness is the primary insight delivered. More generically, without a specific goal in mind, it's hard to give any other guidance.

Comment: I'd also say often, you're just hoping these models can capture the fuzzy insights you already have about your data, in a repeatable/quantititave way. You *know* which texts are topically related, from rich human-level language & world understanding, & you want your models to approach that same level of judgement in a way that *doesn't* require time-consuming attention/annotation/ranking from domain experts. The main "knowledge about the model" you can observe is what it does well & poorly, so that you can try other data, preprocessing, parameters, or models for potential improvements.

Comment: I evaluate my model according to a downstream taks where I recommend the top n results for a seed document. The results are good and match with results of similar scientific papers.
To be precise I'd like to get more insights why certain documents are similar, if there is a bias in my data or how the document length
influences the results. Are there any papers which have dealt with those problems?

Comment: Based on your 2nd comment, it seems like I have to dive deeper in order to understand why it works well & poorly in certain scenarios.

Comment: As similarity between TF-IDF representations is a simple equaltion, reasons *why* 2 diocs score higher than some other 2 docs is strictly mechanistic and can be observed by looking at the raw coordinates & running through the calcs. You could also try to vary certain coordinates (either directly in the representation, or via synthetic alterations to the texts), or clipping out certain dimensions (again, either in the representation, or via text-modification), or re-weighting certain dimensions by adjustment factors, to observe subsequent changes in your end similarities for better or worse.

Comment: But note that lots of machine learning is just automating that iterative adjust-and-test process: "from these initial representations, with these set of benchmark desired results, what sort of calcs/weights best hit those desired results". For example, if you have sets of docs that you know "should" be in the same categories, or nearer than other docs, there are plenty of classification/info-retrival/ranking algorithms you can point at you data/goals & have spit out their best efforts.

Comment: Every different approach may offer different reslts you can then probe, with new/varied/synthetic test data (to experimentally see what makes a big difference, in lengh or word-choices or whatever), or by examining their code & learned-internal-weights. But the specifics will vary per algorithm, and some of their internal workings are scrambled enough to be difficult to interpret except via further experimental probes.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @gojomo: maybe it would help to turn the comments into an answer that can get accepted to signal resolution to the question for other users?